# Validation rules notEmpty and requirePresence

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I would like to know how the various validation rules interact with one another and how they layer up.

I think the easiest way is with a few examples.

Let's assume we are submitting a Post for a blog. So we'll work on the validation in our `PostsTable`.

```php
->notEmpty('title')
->requirePresence('title')
->add('title', 'length', [
    'rule' => ['minLength', 5],
    'message' => 'Must be longer than 5 characers'
]);

->notEmpty('download_speed')
->add('download_speed', 'rule', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
->requirePresence('download_speed')
```

So in this example, are the `notEmpty()` and `requirePresence()` rules actually needed, because the `minLength` will enforce the presence and not empty because obviously an empty string is less than 5 characters?

Similarly in the second example, an empty value will not be numeric so that rule would in turn force it's presence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`requirePresence` is the only built-in rule that is being triggered when the given field doesn't exist, all other rules are only being applied in case the field is actually present, ie `minLength` will not trigger in case the `title` field doesn't exist. So if you need a field to be present and thus validated, then you'll need the `requirePresence` rule.

Also `minLength` will be satisfied by whitespaces, so if you don't consider 5 whitespaces a valid title, then you also cannot ditch the `notEmpty` rule (though you might want to exchange both, `notEmpty` and `minLength` for a custom rule instead that trims the title first, so that 4 whitespaces followed by a char don't make it past the validation, alternatively you could trim the data in your entity).

The only rule that might not be needed in your example is the `notEmpty` rule for the `download_speed` field, because, as you already figured, an empty value isn't a valid number.

Comment: Do `money` and `numeric` overlap in a similar way?

Comment: @DavidYell Note sure what exactly you mean by overlap, however `money` can be satisfied by a simple number like `10`, but it also accepts non-numeric (computer number format wise) values like `10,50` or `10 $`, so these two rules are not interchangable.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check:  != ''
    ->notEmpty('title')

// Check:  isset()
    ->requirePresence('title')

// Check:  5 characters at least but can be white spaces 
    ->add('title', 'length', [
         'rule' => ['minLength', 5],
          'message' => 'Must be at least 5 characters in length'
     ]);

// Check:  5 characters without white spaces behind or after
     ->add('title', 'custom', [
         'rule' => function ($currentData) {                        
              $realLenght = strlen(trim($currentData));  
               if ($realLenght >= 5 ) {return true;}
               return false;                  
          },                                    
         'message' => 'Must be at least 5 characters in length. Avoid unnecessary white spaces''
    ]);
```